# Efficient FFT (or SFFT) for adjacent parts of signal with overlap?

Tags: fft, signal-analysis, fourier-transform, stft

Imaging we have a signal $x$, which is segmented to 50% overlapped vectors $x_1,x_2,..,x_m$ , and we intent to compute FFT of each segment. Is there anyway that we can reduce computation of FFT of each block. I mean, if FFT of $x_1$ has taken and we know $x_2$ has a 50% overlap with $x_1$, so half of $x_2$, have already went through some FFT process.

- Is there any method or modification that reuse this information **to reduce** computations of FFT of each segment based on information of the previous segment?

Comment: Unfortunately a %50 overlap is insufficient for a noticeable performance gain from such a reduction in computation... You may look for sliding DFT, sliding FFT or pruned FFT for similar examples.

Comment: @Fat32 , I am developing an idea on this regard, and I feel your point (about insufficiency of 50% overlap) is close to it. How much  overlap suffices for a noticeable gain?, how? I'd appreciate if you share your knowledge on that.

Comment: [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/37213/online-dft-algorithm/37216#37216) question and its answers might shed some light.

Comment: It is what I was looking for, exactly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method might be to split your length $N$ overlapping FFTs up, so that you compute the $\frac{N}{2}$-point FFT of each block of samples that come in. Then, in order to get the $N$-point FFT that you want, you can combine the last two $\frac{N}{2}$-point results with appropriate twiddle factors.

This would technically do what you want, but in most cases (especially on contemporary PC-like platforms with good FFT libraries), it's not going to be appreciably (if at all) faster than just doing the overlapping $N$-point FFTs.

Comment: Interesting method, I looked out the web for it, thank you. But this recursive FFT computation from smaller FFTs method you've mentioned seem to increases computations overall and I think it is more suitable when memory is limited. However though, I wasn't aware of such a trick, thank you!

Comment: It shouldn't require any more computations; in fact, this is why the FFT works. The complexity reduction comes from decomposing one transform into multiple smaller transforms. You would just be doing one of those steps here manually. As I said before, though, it probably won't be any faster for you.